# UIManager setLookAndFeel is not working

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, uimanager

I try to use `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` function to change the appearance of my java application but it makes no effect to the visual appearance of my `JFrame`/buttons.  I use `Netbeans 7.4` and my application is `Java Swing Desktop Application`.

```
     /**
     * Main method launching the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("init");
        launch(JavaMysqlTestApp.class, args);        
    }
```

I used

- `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel`
- `javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel`
- `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel`
- `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`
- `UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName()`

but non of them changed anything of appearance of my companent. How can I make this function take effect?

Comment: Is `launch(JavaMysqlTestApp.class, args);` launch another application?

Comment: It is a `java desktop application` not `java application`. so the confution comes from that thing i think. now i used `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` method in `@Override protected void startup()` function, now it works!

Answer (score 1):

One might inspect all look-and-feels:

```
    try {
        LookAndFeel laf = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            ...
            if (laf.getName().equals(info.getName())) {
                ...;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
            | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Probably the look-and-feel is **set a second time**. For beginners finding this question: L&F only works for **swing**; if one uses **awt** Button (instead of JButton) or JavaFX, you will see no change too.

You could do:

```
UIManager.addPropertyChangeListener(...);
```

and on any change do your change afterwards.